# Show Multiple Alerts with different time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Show alert for different time different messages from core data. i tried this code
show alert for 2 seconds 3 seconds ,4 seconds etc...

```
 if (fetchedObjectsData.count > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Return data Count is ====== %lu",(unsigned long)[fetchedObjectsData count]);

    for (int i=0; i <[fetchedObjectsData count] ; i++)
    {
        NSManagedObject *firstManagedObject = (NSManagedObject *)[fetchedObjectsData objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * distance = [firstManagedObject valueForKey:@"distance"];
        NSString * typeAlert = [firstManagedObject valueForKey:@"type"];
        NSString * displayTime = [firstManagedObject valueForKey:@"display_time"];
        NSString * content = [firstManagedObject valueForKey:@"content"];
        NSString * title = [firstManagedObject valueForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"How much time you here === %d",i);

    if ([distance intValue]>=0 && [distance intValue]<5)
    {
        if ([typeAlert isEqualToString:@"1"]&& [displayTime isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            NSLog(@"typeAlert 1 0 === %d",i);

        }
       if ([typeAlert isEqualToString:@"1"]&& ![displayTime isEqualToString:@"0"])
       {
            NSLog(@"typeAlert 1 1 === %d",i);

           dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, [displayTime intValue] * NSEC_PER_SEC);
           dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

               UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                     alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                     message:content
                                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

               [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
           });


       }}}

}else {

    NSLog(@"there's no  with same id. Use insert method");
}
```

display these alert on the app delegate class
title and messages are taking from core data table

i need to show alert one by one one like for 2 seconds alert show after that next alert for stay in 3 seconds like that

Comment: What kind of problem you are facing ? Please mention here.

Comment: @CodeChanger the alert is not showing, i need to show alert one by one one like for 2 seconds alert show after that next alert for stay in 3 seconds like that

Comment: Ok so for that you have to design custom alert as if user not dismiss first alert you can not able to show another one.

Comment: @CodeChanger Automatically want to dismiss, and next alert want show.if i press pause want to stay there is it possible

Comment: Yes thats possible with `[alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:<#(BOOL)#> completion:<#^(void)completion#>]`  with this method

Comment: @CodeChanger is my above code is right?  where i want to call the dismiss